# Easy way to switch between content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I just made a script that shows/hides content with Jquery when you click on tabs above the content (it also changes the color of the tab that was clicked). Everything works fine (Result: https://jsfiddle.net/e572s3oq/embedded/result/) but i think there is an other way to switch between the content that makes it easier to add more tabs. I would be really glad if someone could help me. And i hope you understand my intention. (Please excuse my english and ask me if you have any remaining questions)

Here is my Code (I think only the jQuery code is relevant):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tab:first-child").click(function() {
    $(".content p:nth-child(2)").css('display', 'none');
    $(".tab:nth-child(2)").css('background-color', '#F5F7F7');
    $(".tab:first-child").css('background-color', 'white');
    $(".content p:first-child").css('display', 'block');
  });

  $(".tab:nth-child(2)").click(function() {
    $(".content p:first-child").css('display', 'none');
    $(".tab:first-child").css('background-color', '#F5F7F7');
    $(".tab:nth-child(2)").css('background-color', 'white');
    $(".content p:nth-child(2)").css('display', 'block');
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.tab {
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.tab:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab:first-child {
  background-color: white;
}
.tab:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #F5F7F7;
}
.content {
  width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.content p {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content p:first-child {
  display: block;
}
.content p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=wrapper>
  <div class="tab">
    PAGE 1
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    PAGE 2
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Content1</p>
    <p>Content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.content p').hide();
    $('.tab').css('background-color', '#F5F7F7');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    $('.content p').eq($(this).index()).css('display', 'block');
});
```

What basically is happening is:

- We first, by default, hide all the `p` elements within the `.content` div.
- We also set `background-color` to `#F5F7F7` for all the `.tab` elements.
- Then, you can target the current `.tab` element by the use of `$(this)` and set its `background-color` to `white`.
- Finally, we can target a particular `p` element within `.content` div by using the current **[`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** of the current `.tab` element and then we feed this `.index()` to another method of jQuery called **[`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** which then gets us the desired `p` element.

***Snippet:***

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.content p').hide();
    $('.tab').css('background-color', '#F5F7F7');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    $('.content p').eq($(this).index()).css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
body, html {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#ecf0f1;
}
#wrapper {
    width:260px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:100px;
}
.tab {
    width:84px;
    height:30px;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#7f8c8d;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F5F7F7;
}
.tab:hover { cursor:pointer; }
.tab:first-child { background-color: white; }
.content {
    width:260px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:white;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.content p {
    color:#7f8c8d;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.content p:first-child {
    display:block;
}
.content p:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=wrapper>
    <div class="tab">PAGE 1</div>
    <div class="tab">PAGE 2</div>
    <div class="tab">PAGE 3</div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne lorem dolorem eos. His ex verear tincidunt, ea causae nominavi voluptua ius. Sit ne nibh qqqqqqdeserunt petentium, nam nisl volumus tincidunt ne. Ut vel dictas posidonium sadipscing, nominavi comprehensam duo no. Et quis prima exerci pro, idque ignota fastidii vel cu, id eum solet mollis definitionem. Habeo dolore postulant te pri, duo ut electram incorrupte, ea melius omittantur vel. Alii graeco bonorum pri et. Aliquip similique cum at. Ad per perfecto expetendis mediocritatem, pro percipitur ullamcorper complectitur ex. His falli aeque fierent cu, reque philosophia mel ex. Ad eum dicat platonem voluptatibus, eu vim alia adhuc justo, minimum consequuntur usu ex. Eos dolorem maiorum scaevola no, aliquid verterem ut per. Mea et feugiat vivendum, id graece iriure mel. Nihil debitis necessitatibus et nec. Ut has mazim option mandamus. Veri adipisci eloquentiam eos ea, soleat dissentiunt te mel, vel at debitis recteque petentium.</p>
        <p>Id graece similique sea, ex duo dico dicam indoctum, nam animal tritani adversarium in. Eu mea veniam nonumes sententiae, ius iudico moderatius cu. Vidisse pericula suavitate vim ne, dicam neglegentur ei ius, ne illud viderer feugait his. Sit modus adolescens in, duo te amet suavitate tincidunt. Soleat signiferumque te per, no eos debet singulis neglegentur, cu vis natum falli expetendis. Vix tollit dicunt mediocrem eu, mei et equidem civibus. Eum dicat efficiantur definitionem ne. Ei mei wisi vidisse appetere. An sit nominavi lobortis, liber legimus epicuri sea an. Ne habeo ludus expetendis sit, ne posse tantas voluptaria nec, id elit volumus quaestio pro. Interpretaris conclusionemque ea eum, tollit insolens no mel Id graece similique sea, ex duo dico dicam indoctum, nam animal tritani adversarium in. Eu mea veniam nonumes sententiae, ius iudico moderatius cu. Vidisse pericula suavitate vim ne, dicam neglegentur ei ius, ne illud viderer feugait his. Sit modus adolescens in, duo te amet suavitate tincidunt. Soleat signiferumque te per, no eos debet singulis neglegentur, cu vis natum falli expetendis. Vix tollit dicunt mediocrem eu, mei et equidem civibus. Eum dicat efficiantur definitionem ne. Ei mei wisi vidisse appetere. An sit nominavi lobortis, liber legimus epicuri sea an. Ne habeo ludus expetendis sit, ne posse tantas voluptaria nec, id elit volumus quaestio pro. Interpretaris conclusionemque ea eum, tollit insolens no mel.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne lorem dolorem eos. His ex verear tincidunt, ea causae nominavi voluptua ius. Sit ne nibh qqqqqqdeserunt petentium, nam nisl volumus tincidunt ne. Ut vel dictas posidonium sadipscing, nominavi comprehensam duo no. Et quis prima exerci pro, idque ignota fastidii vel cu, id eum solet mollis definitionem. Habeo dolore postulant te pri, duo ut electram incorrupte, ea melius omittantur vel. Alii graeco bonorum pri et. Aliquip similique cum at. Ad per perfecto expetendis mediocritatem, pro percipitur ullamcorper complectitur ex. His falli aeque fierent cu, reque philosophia mel ex. Ad eum dicat platonem voluptatibus, eu vim alia adhuc justo, minimum consequuntur usu ex. Eos dolorem maiorum scaevola no, aliquid verterem ut per. Mea et feugiat vivendum, id graece iriure mel. Nihil debitis necessitatibus et nec. Ut has mazim option mandamus. Veri adipisci eloquentiam eos ea, soleat dissentiunt te mel, vel at debitis recteque petentium.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modified a few styles in CSS and added more content in HTML for the above snippet. Hope this helps.